# How to run my program on before login on windows XP?

Tags: c#

Hai,
          I have a simple smile face program in c# which stored login time in d:\time.txt file.But when I add the program  at"gpedit.msc" then
          Computer Configuration->Windows Settings->Scripts(Start up/Shutdown)->stratup->DOUBLE CLICK then Add the "my.exe", for every single login. I found that Its worked only first time when i boot the system.but If I restart the machine after suppose 15-20 mins, the time not change in file and even the smile face also not comes more then one time login.

anyone can help me to run this program every time when i login in PC.

Comment: Could you post the code you're using to create the file and write to it so we can see if there's anything wrong there.
Also, check the event log, see if you have any errors reported by your program.

Comment: You can simply copy it to the startup folder in the programs menu.

Answer (score 1):

What you put under Startup/Shutdown runs at startup/shutdown, not logon/logoff.

When you want to run them at login, you need to put them under Logon/Logoff.

You'll find that under User Configuration -> Windows Settings.

Comment: I have added that as given instructions but the exe not running at beginning .what to do?

Answer (score 1):

As i am in hurry, i can not add code atm.
 Another approach would be creating your programm as a service (which is simply done by usind the corresponding project template within visual studio). This service would listen to a windows message that is fired whenever a user is logged on.
A service delivers also some further advantaged you might want to use ;)